# Source by bashrc when I exit an 'ssh' session

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal, shell

I'm on OS X and am using iTerm2.

I've updated my Bash profile on several of my servers so that when I `ssh` into them I can tell at a glance from the tabs what boxes I'm on. When I exit from an `ssh` session, the shell that initiated the `ssh` session does not source `~/.bashrc` again (which I understand to be normal operating procedure), so my tab titles and colors persist with the titles and colors they were from my `ssh` session.

Normally when I exit an `ssh` session, I will also exit the shell on the computer that I'm physically using as well. But for consistency's sake, I would like to revert my iterm2 tabs to the appropriate titles and colors for the shell they represent when I exit an `ssh` session.

Is there a way to source my `.bashrc` when I exit an `ssh` session?

In all of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, and `~/.bash_logout` I have the following lines:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND=''
echo -e "\033];test machine name\007"
```

When I exit an `ssh` session, it looks like none of these Bash files in my home directory are sourced to reprint the tab title. When I manually source them with `source ~/.bashrc` the tab title reprints just fine. So, the syntax is not wrong.

Comment: Take a look at `~/.bash_logout`.

Comment: @Cyrus A good idea that I didn't try. However, I have tried it and the problem persists. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to be command-specific, then redefining `ssh` (as mentioned in another answer) is probably the best approach.

If you actually prefer something more general, `bash` has a [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-PROMPT_005fCOMMAND) shell variable you can set to run a command (or multiple commands) before the shell prompt is printed, which would happen right after `ssh` (or any other command) returns to the shell.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: You need to put the single quotes in the right place, i.e. `export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -e "\033];test machine name\007"'`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to source my .bashrc when I exit an ssh session?

Yes, define a shell function:

```
ssh() { command ssh "$@"; source ~/.bashrc; }
```

Comment: You might want to use `command ssh` instead of hardcoding the path.

Comment: @glennjackman Good suggestion.  Answer updated to used `command`.

Comment: @glennjackman Can one of you point me to a resource to explain this so I can understand what's going on? Googling 'bash command' is obviously not working for me lol

Comment: `command` is a shell built-in. To find out what some arbitrary command is, in bash type `type -a command` -- that will show you all the implementations, be they built-ins, functions, aliases, or commands in your $PATH. To get the documentation for a bash builtin, type `help command`

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks. I have put the line `ssh() { command ssh "$@"; source ~/.bashrc; }` exactly as that as the last line in my `~/.bashrc` and when I exit an ssh session the tab title persists with machine name of the ssh session.

Comment: @smilebomb Try instead `ssh() { command ssh "$@"; source ~/.bashrc; echo "HELLO"; }`.  If, after exiting an ssh session, you see `HELLO` then  this function is working.  If you still have the unwanted tab title, then the problem is with `~/.bashrc`.